# What type of cables do I need for this video card?

Tags: display, cable, dvi

I am building my own PC ([the one Jeff outlined](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/07/building-a-pc-part-vii-rebooting.html))

I am using the [Sapphire HD 6850 PCIE Video Card (100315L)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0047ZGIUK) as my video card.

I went bought DVI cables, but they didn't work. Apparently, these cables are DVD-D, but the DVI outputs are some other kind of DVI. Now I have to drive back to the store and return,

Here is a picture of the DVI outputs on the card:

[image]

What kind of DVI cables do I need for this?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to connect the card to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It possesses the following ports:

1 x HDMI

1 x DisplayPort

2 x DVI

What monitor are you using? Most monitors come with DVI cables these days, so why would you have to buy one? Or, are you building just the desktop to sell to someone?

Anyway, for that port on your Sapphire 6850, you can use either a DUAL-LINK DVI-I or DVI-D cable. This is the reason why.

The port on the Sapphire 6850 is a DUAL-LINK DVI-I port. However, a cable with a DUAL-LINK DVI-D connector can also be used since it will fit into a DUAL-LINK DVI-I port. If your Sapphire 6850 had a DUAL-LINK DVI-D port, then it would only accept DUAL-LINK DVI-D connectors (not DVI-I).

So, either one in your case.

Comment: I have two 27 Inch Samsung monitor (with TV tuner).  They with HDMI cables. I may have bent pins or something - the DVI-D will not go in despite using a little force.

Comment: What is the model number of your Samsung monitors? Is your graphics card new from the retailer?

Comment: It is a samsung P2770HD. http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/monitors/LS27EMNKUY/ZA. Yes, the graphics card is brand new from the retailer (Amazon)

Answer (score 2):

You should read about [DVI on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface#Connector). You should be able to plug DVI-D cables into DVI-I sockets.

If you're not seeing a display, either there's some problem with your hardware setup or the default output device is set to the wrong port.